# Dividing a loop task among threads using OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp

Suppose I want to run the following loop between threats (say 4 threads) such that each thread is in charge of calculating (N/4) where N is the number of rows of the matrix.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(i,j,M) shared(Matrix)
{

#pragma omp for schedule(static)
  for(i=0; i<N; i++) 
  {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
       M[i][j]= Matrix[i][j] + (Matrix[i][j] * Matrix[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: Should I explicitly specify the beginning and the end of each chunk of the matrix that each thread will calculate or OpenMP will automatically distribute the job between the threads? The reason behind this question is that I've read somewhere that OpenMP will automatically distribute the job between the threads but when I implemented it, it gave me fault segmentation error.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, when you use the `for` pragma inside of the `parallel` pragma, then OpenMP will automatically distribute loop's work among threads. Also did you mean `Matrix[i][j] = Matrix[i][j] + (Matrix[i][j] * Matrix[j][i]);` instead of `M[i][j]= Matrix[i][j] + (Matrix[i][j] * Matrix[j][i]);` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, I mean storing the results in M[][].

Comment: If I want to EXPLICITLY specify the chunks to each thread, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use `schedule(static, chunk)`. This will give each thread a chunk of iterations to process. Once every thread is finished with its chunk, it will take on the next chunk until all N iterations are completed. Another way that gives all the power into you hands is to use `#pragma omp parallel` without `#pragma omp for` and divide iterations among threads by yourself based on `omp_get_num_threads` and `omp_get_thread_num` functions.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Well Explained

Comment: I am not sure why would your code crash (in my test it did not), but be aware that `private` clause only allocates your variables on the thread's stack. So before and also after the parallel section the value of `M` will be undefined (probably not what you want). I think it should be declared as `shared`.

Comment: I'll check that ... Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @jcxz is right: `M` should be shared not private.